# Проверка на поддержку CSS3

Tags: javascript

Можно ли с помощью js проверить, поддерживается ли CSS3 браузером или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть готовые библиотеки. Я использую [modernizr.com](http://modernizr.com)

Необходимо подключить модернизр в шапке, а не в конце body.

После загрузки страницы тегу html проставляются классы:
cssgradients или no-cssgradients
далее в CSS можно делать так:

```
.selector { CSS3-код градиента }
.no-cssgradients .selector { однопиксельная картинка с градиентом }
```

Чтобы отследить случай отключенного JS, следует тегу html проставить класс no-js. Если JS отключен, этот класс так и останется. Если включен, заменится на js.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 еще не стандартизирован, и разные браузеры могут поддерживать или нет разные его фичи.

Так что нужно проверять конкретную фичу, которую вы хотите использовать.