# Градиент для IE на css, в т.ч. свойство hover

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Доброго всем времени суток, господа (2й раз за сегодня).

Собственно код - [использование градиента](http://jsfiddle.net/h7DDF/).

Для тех, у кого не IE - все нормально, у кого IE - я специально прописал голубой цвет. Вот интересует, как сделать, чтобы в IE тоже работало. (на css это возможно? без js/jq)

p.s. Высоколобые сразу скажут... пропиши:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#666666');
```

Так вот, я поясню, если это свойство вписать, в css то в `:hover` оно не работает.

Comment: Забей. Пользователи IE должны страдать, разработчик - не должен

Comment: Разработчик IE должен гореть в аду

Comment: neoascetic, я был бы доволен ответом, что IE9 не умеет делать то, о чем я спросил. И это возможно не на css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE - кошмар для любого веб-дизайнера =). По теме, код какой указан ниже как правило успешно работает на более новее версиях этого браузера, хотя как пишут статьи то ИЕ 6 *должен* успешно справятся.

> filter:
> progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799',endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0
> );

Выход реализации градиента во всех браузерах - это использовать картинку размерами 1х32 или 32х1... Как по мне это лучший выход для вашей проблемы. Размер картинки являются примером.

Comment: немного обновил. дописал. ничего не работает. http://jsfiddle.net/h7DDF/1/

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=732 - вот наверно статья как раз для Вас, правда тот хак всеравно где-то меня когда-то подводил. Но статья написана хорошо, там в общем не только градиет, а вообще css3 для ИЕ

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/94438/). Довольно подробно и ясно описано, а главное - работает.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри тут - они заглушку делают: [Gradient Patterns](http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/).

Comment: Что то до меня не дошла глубокая мысль этой ссылки. По ссылке - есть переход, от одного цвета, к другому. Градиента нету.

Answer (score 0):

Работает в таком виде в IE9:

```
// html
<table class="ttx"><tr><td>
    kill me... kill me please !!1
</td></tr></table>

// css
.ttx {
    font-size:42px;
    background-color:#99CCFF;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #666);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333, #666);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333, #666);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #666);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#666666');
}

.ttx:hover {
    font-size:42px;
    background-color:#4488CC;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#666, #333);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#666, #333);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#666, #333);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, #333);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#666666', endColorstr='#333333');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы все же не использовать картинку? Да, это не всегда удобно, но в большинстве случаев это хороший фикс, а главное, что работает во всех браузерах не понимающих градиенты, а не тольоко в IE. Определим, умеет ли браузер делать градиенты или нет, например модернизром: [проверка на поддержку css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130477/javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D1%83-css3).
Если умеет, то делаем кодом. Если нет, грузим картинку.

**Ограничения**

1) Наведение. Если в состоянии :hover грузить другую картинку с другим градиентом, то время, которое уходит на подгрузку существенно. И в первый раз эффект срабатывает не сразу. Чинится вырезанием не просто картинки, а спрайта: вырезаем не 32px высотой, а 64px. Где первые 32px это градиент в обычном состоянии, а вторые 32px - градиент для наведения. В состоянии hover теперь меняем не картинку, а [background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position). Так вот ограничение тут на высоту. Если мы точно не знаем высоту (32px в примере), то спрайт не прокатить. Либо ищем способ вытянуть сразу обе картинки.

2) Неизвестная/поехавшая высота. Картинка в этом случае замостится. Сделай высоту в 33px и повторившаяся картинка сильно все испортит. Выход: повторять картинку только по одному измерению (ширине), а по высоте ее прижимать к низу. "оставшиеся" сверху пиксели заливать цветом начала градиента на картинке. Ограничение: при сильно варьирующейся высоте, скажем в несколько раз, ничего не получится, а градиент будет только в нижней части. Да и задуматься стоит о том, уместен ли там градиент вообще, если его так тянет.

3) Отключенный JS. Да, не сработает модернизр вообще. Это ситуация достаточно редкая и вообще врядли что либо можно в этом случае сделать, кроме как просто использовать цвет.

Вопрос автору: вы знаете высоту в вашем случае? Или она определяется контентом?